# Error al compilar y hacer ng serve de un proyecto de Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

cuando intento compilar cualquier proyecto de angular, me da el siguiente error:

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)

at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

at Object.<anonymous>
```

(C:\Users\xaide\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\src\logger\i
ndex.js:13:10)

```
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
```

Ayer cuando guarde todo iba perfectamente y hoy al intentar hacer el ng serve me da este error

Comment: Has actualizado algún módulo o dependencia del proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola revisa que versión de node estás usando y corrobora que tiene actualizado el cli de angular. Si no es así actualiza el cli de angular, borrá node_modules, instala de nuevo las dependencias y hace un ng build. Es raro que sin tocar nada deje de funcionar, pero puede ser que cuando funcionaba, este lo hacía con alguno de sus ficheros cacheados en memoria y es lógico que luego del apagado este ya no está disponible.

Comment: La respuesta que das no se ajusta a los estándares que pide StackOverflow sobre la calidad de las respuestas. Por favor, lee como responder: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .Tu respues actual encajaría mejor en la parte de comentarios que como respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Reinstale node y angular/cli y volvió a funcionar... No se cual sería el problema pero ya está solucionado. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: @JorgeGuz por razones de reputación y falta de puntos no me dejaba escribir comentarios y mi respuesta era lo correcto. saludos.